# turn a line into a rectangle

Tags: math, graphics, vector

I have a method that draws a line between two points.  This works pretty well, but now I want to make this line into a rectangle.

How can I get the points on the left and right side of each of the line points to make it into a rectangle that I can draw?

It is almost as though I need to somehow figure out how to get perpendicular lines programatically....

Comment: watch out, IBM has that patented! http://www.forbes.com/asap/2002/0624/044.html

Comment: that is insane... fat lines should be free for everyone

Comment: I may have messed up explaining this here.  The line is in the middle of the rectangle.  So imagine a rectangle with a line cutting it in half lengthwise, not diagonal

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm guessing you basically want fat lines? Lets assume the line is specified by two points `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` we then have:

```
float dx = x1 - x0; //delta x
float dy = y1 - y0; //delta y
float linelength = sqrtf(dx * dx + dy * dy);
dx /= linelength;
dy /= linelength;
//Ok, (dx, dy) is now a unit vector pointing in the direction of the line
//A perpendicular vector is given by (-dy, dx)
const float thickness = 5.0f; //Some number
const float px = 0.5f * thickness * (-dy); //perpendicular vector with lenght thickness * 0.5
const float py = 0.5f * thickness * dx;
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(x0 + px, y0 + py);
glVertex2f(x1 + px, y1 + py);
glVertex2f(x1 - px, y1 - py);
glVertex2f(x0 - px, y0 - py);
glEnd();
```

Since you're using OpenGL ES I guess you'll have to convert the immediate mode rendering (`glBegin`, `glEnd`, etc) to `glDrawElements`. You'll also have to convert the quad into two triangles.

One final thing, I'm a little tired and uncertain if the resulting quad is counterclockwise or clockwise so turn of backface culling when you try this out (`glDisable(GL_CULL)`).

Comment: Andreas, I have to replace (-dy) by (dy). I think that's because you have e.g. 'y0 + py' not 'y0 - py'.

Comment: @ChrisJJ is right, I tried to fix the answer but the edit was rejected. Change the signs of the 'x' parameters of the `glVertex2f` methods to match the signs of the 'y' parameters. `glVertex2f(x0 + px, y0 + py);
glVertex2f(x1 + px, y1 + py);
glVertex2f(x1 - px, y1 - py);
glVertex2f(x0 - px, y0 - py);`

Comment: @Ryan What reason was given for the rejection?

Comment: @ChrisJJ "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer." It was voted down 3 to 2. I don't know why fixing broken code 'makes no sense'. I just tried editing it again.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've asked this question with OpenGL taged I'll assume that you wish for a solution that is close to OpenGL.

As you know you have two points that make up a line. Lets call them x1,y1 and x2, y2

Lets also assume that x1, y1 is the top left point and x2, y2 is the bottom right.

Your 4 points to plot will be [you need to perserve order to make a rectangle with GL_LINES)

```
Height:y1-y1   
Width: x2-x1 

(x1, y1)
(x1+width, y1)
(x2, y2)
(x2-width, y2)
```

Answer (score -2):

drawRect(x,y,w,h)

tl = (x,y)
tr = (x+w, y)
br = (x+w, y+h)
bl = (x, y+h)